# React 15 not compatible with React-redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

I am trying to upgrade to the freshly released react@15.0.0-rc.1 on my project that is also using react-redux@^4.4.0 package. 
However when I try to run the upgrade suggested in the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/03/07/react-v15-rc1.html)

```
npm install --save react@15.0.0-rc.1 react-dom@15.0.0-rc.1
```

It comes up with an error because the versions are not compatible:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-test-utils@0.14.7 wants react@^0.14.7
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.0 wants react@^0.14.0
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: This has been raised as a ticket. https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/319

Comment: By the way, you can use `npm@3.x` where missing peer dependencies are just a warning and not an error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just published `react-redux@4.4.1` which allows React 15 as a peer dependency.

Note that you can use `npm@3.x` which doesn’t enforce peer dependencies. This way, you don’t have to wait for project authors to update their packages.

Comment: Sorry if this is inept but...does this mean the import of PropTypes from React in the tutorials will work without a problem?

Comment: I saw that you are supposed to grab PropTypes from the prop-types package. I'm not sure I completely understand how the dependencies marshal or what I should do to allow this to work.